# Is there any alternative to repeatedly typing INSERT INTO "TABLE" in sql to input data?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTSFILE
( UNIQUEID INTEGER,
NAME VARCHAR(20),
DATEOFBIRTH VARCHAR(20),
MATHS INTEGER,
ENGLISHSCIENCE INTEGER,
CTA INTEGER,
SST INTEGER,
AVG FLOAT
 );
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1001,'RHYTHMGUPTA',27062004,50,60,70,80,90);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1002,'SUDHIRJAIN',22072005,40,60,70,80,90);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1003,'HARSHRAJ',01092003,100,100,100,100,100);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1004,'HARSHVERMA',05052000,00,00,70,80,90);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1005,'HARSHSINGHAL',01012004,00,60,70,80,90);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1006,'ABHAYSINGH',23092004,50,60,70,80,90);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1007,'ANANTTRIPATHI',28122004,50,60,70,80,100);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1008,'JOHNCENA',13072004,50,60,70,80,90);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1009,'IITBOMBAY',23062004,50,0,70,80,90);
INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE
VALUES(1010,'IITKHARAGPUR',01042004,50,60,70,90,90);
```

is there any alternative so that I don't have to type INSERT INTO STUDENTSFILE again and again?

I tried adding braces and removing semicolon but it did not work

Comment: no, you can add every tuple and seperate them by comma